# Relacionamentos utilizando função OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso relacionar uma tabela de um servidor e uma view de outro. 
Pesquisei sobre a função **OPENDATASOURCE** e posteriormente implementei-a na query. Ao executar, o programa me retorna esta mensagem e não entendi onde esta o erro.

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
>   Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".

SELECT 
ZMDDIGITAIS.ID, 
ZMDDIGITAIS.CODCOLIGADA, 
ZMDCOLIGADA.NOMEFANTASIA,
ZMDDIGITAIS.CHAPA, 
F.NOME, 
ZMDDIGITAIS.RECCREATEDBY, 
ZMDDIGITAIS.RECCREATEDON
FROM 
ZMDDIGITAIS
INNER JOIN OPENDATASOURCE ('SQLNCLI','Data Source=NomeServidor;User ID=Usuario;Password=Senha;').[CorporeRM].dbo.FUNCIONARIOS AS F 
ON ZMDDIGITAIS.CHAPA = F.CHAPA AND ZMDDIGITAIS.CODCOLIGADA = F.CODCOLIGADA
INNER JOIN ZMDCOLIGADA 
ON ZMDDIGITAIS.CODCOLIGADA = ZMDCOLIGADA.CODCOLIGADA
WHERE ZMDDIGITAIS.CODCOLIGADA = 1

Comment: Para melhorar sua pergunta, eu traria a *query* que executou para gerar esse log de erro.

Comment: Alterei a publicação para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: A mensagem de erro indica as prováveis causas do erro; analise uma a uma.